# searching for sentences that are a question in a file

Tags: python, file-read

```
f = open("data.txt", "rt")
lines = f.read()
#word = line.split()
for line in lines:
    if line == 'how' or line == 'what' or line == 'where':
        print(lines, "Yes")
    else:
        print(lines, "No")
f.close()
```

I am trying to read a file and look for sentences that have how, what, where, etc. Basically sentences that are a question. And printing the sentences along with a Yes or No accordingly.

```
Format of Input file: 
how are you 
it's 7 o'clock  
where is your food

Format of Output file:
how are you  Yes
it's 7 o'clock  No
where is your food Yes
```

But my code is giving no output.

Comment: Try this instead: `if line.startswith( 'how') or line.startswith('what') or line.startswith('where'):`

Comment: I tried it but it's still giving me no output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `if line == 'how' or line == 'what' or line == 'where':` suggests to me that you might want to use the logic of keyword [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any):

```
f = open("data.txt", "rt")
lines = f.readlines()
f.close()

with open('data_out.txt', 'w') as f:
    for line in lines:
        if any(question_word in line for question_word in ['how', 'what', 'where']):
            output = '{} {}\n'.format(line.strip('\n'), "Yes")
            print(output)
            f.write(output)
        else:
            output = '{} {}\n'.format(line.strip('\n'), "No")
            print(output)
            f.write(output)
```

---

```
how are you  Yes
it's 7 o'clock   No
where is your food Yes
```

Comment: Just one more question, how do I write the answers to another file?

Comment: similiarly as you read the file, but open a new file with `'w'` (write permissions). I modified the result to write output to a file at the same time it prints. hope that helps :)